# Object instance is cast to Object after assignment

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have class to which I set property values in a `for` loop. One of the properties is object, class respectively.

But after the `for` loop ends, this property loses its type and it is cast to simple `Object`. Why?

```
public setAttributes(data:any):void {
   for (var name in data) {
       if (this.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            switch (name) {
                case 'restaurant':
                    this.restaurant = new Restaurant(data.restaurant);
                    console.log(this.restaurant); //log 1
                default:
                    this[name] = data[name];
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(this.restaurant); //log 2
    this.restaurant = new Restaurant(data['restaurant']);
    console.log(this.restaurant); //log 3
}
```

Calling function with

```
this.setAttributes({
    title: 'test',
    restaurant: {
        title: 'restaurant test'
    }
})
```

results in

```
Restaurant {title: 'restaurant test'} //log 1
Object {title: 'restaurant test'} //log 2
Restaurant {title: 'restaurant test'} //log 3
```

Why the second log (*//log 2*) has type **Object** but not **Restaurant**?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `break` statement here to avoid overwriting `this.restaurant` right after you initialize it:

```
public setAttributes(data:any):void {
   for (var name in data) {
       if (this.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            switch (name) {
                case 'restaurant':
                    this.restaurant = new Restaurant(data.restaurant);
                    console.log(this.restaurant); //log 1
                    break; // oops! was falling through
                default:
                    this[name] = data[name];
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(this.restaurant); //log 2
    this.restaurant = new Restaurant(data['restaurant']);
    console.log(this.restaurant); //log 3
}
```

Comment: thank you :) I was wondering about some JS behaviour I do not know. And look at that, what a silly mistake